# CSS - how to show 3 same size images in a container but have the images on the sides cut off purposely

Tags: css, position, overflow

I am trying to achieve the effect below in the example, so that the two images not in the middle are cut off purposely, so that when the browser is smaller, the user will actually see the full images. I have tried endless variations on this css:

```
width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 670px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: absolute;
```

and seem to be getting nowhere
[image]

Comment: Could you provide the html?

Comment: Only for the example in question. Tried replicating it but to no avail. https://inakisoria.com/

Comment: @RichStevens Is there a problem to copy that code from the site?

Answer (score 0):

Just use display: flex; for the container and align all the images in the middle.

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

You can see and test this example here: https://codepen.io/bIropka/pen/WNramag

Comment: This will create a scrollbar on smaller screens

Comment: It is doesn't relate to this case. But if you don't need the scrollbar:

width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;

Answer (score 0):

So I've used `flexbox` to get them all on the same line.
Added `overflow: hidden;` to `.image-wrapper` so the image can overflow without getting a scrollbar.

on the first `.image-wrapper` I've added `direction: rtl;` so it goes out of the box on the left instead of the right side.

```
.container .image-wrapper:nth-of-type(2n) {
   min-width: max-content;
}
```

This is to make sure the middle wrapper will always be the full image size

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container .image-wrapper {
  padding: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  min-height: max-content;
  position: relative;
}

.container .image-wrapper:first-of-type {
  direction: rtl;
}

.container .image-wrapper:nth-of-type(2n) {
  min-width: max-content;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/400" alt="">
  </div>
</div>
```